# How can we find friends or import contacts in Twitter (2020)?

Tags: twitter

At the moment, my Twitter account only has 24 followers. I plan to increase that by finding and inviting my friends/connections in Gmail or other social networks. It is a very common approach in other social networks such as LinkedIn.

I have searched a lot on the internet, but the instructions seem outdated.

Does anyone know how to do this in the new Twitter UI?

**PS:**

I also asked @TwitterSupport, but they did not answer.

Here is [my question in Quora](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-can-we-find-friends-or-import-contacts-in-Twitter-2019), but nobody answered.

Answer (score 0):

These instructions seem valid as of today: [Twitter Help: How to upload and manage your contacts](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/upload-your-contacts-to-search-for-friends)

On iOS:

> 1. In the top menu, tap your profile icon, then tap Settings and privacy.
> 2. Tap Privacy and safety.
> 3. Under Discoverability and contacts, tap Discoverability and contacts.
> 4. Tap Sync address book contacts. When you sync your contacts, contacts from your device’s address book will be uploaded to Twitter on an ongoing basis.
> 5. The accounts of contacts from your address book who are already on Twitter will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's easy; follow these instructions:

1. In the top menu, tap your profile icon, then tap Settings and privacy.
2. Tap Privacy and safety.
3. Under Discoverability and contacts, tap Discoverability and contacts.
4. Tap Sync address book contacts. When you sync your contacts, contacts from your device’s address book will be uploaded to Twitter on an ongoing basis.
5. The accounts of contacts from your address book who are already on Twitter will be shown.